# Performance issue with Dropdown controls

Tags: c#, telerik

I have a requirement where i have to render large number of Dropdown controls on page,number of items in dropdown varies and it can goes up to 1000 items(not my design but my client). I am using Telerik controls on my page. As the number of controls on page increases the performance decreases and browser starts lagging sometimes it stop responding and hangs. To make it more worst client want this to be supporte on IE browser.Even design change is not acceptable. Please have a look to attached image. I am struggling since long to clear this but no luck.

**My functionality in brief:** By clicking on Add link new row is added on page dynamically(postback, redrawing all the controls again). On value change of first dropdown (i.e. Field column) the controls in Value column changes(again postback and redrawing all controls)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see you're using individual controls that cost a lot of resources, and there is no other way to avoid it, more controls, more resources are needed.

In my opinion you could use a RadGridView with embbeded Controls and play with the appearence to give it the same look and feel, if you do it well the client may not note the diference.